# SQL - Get rows where all columns are in a list that have the same value in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database as follows:

```
drinks_id   ingredients_master_id
1           2
1           3
1           4
2           2
2           4
3           5
```

And I'm looking for a query where I can give it a list of ingredients_master_id such as 2,4 and it returns all of the drinks_id's that have exactly 2,4.

So in this case if I gave it ingredients_master_id 2,4,5 it would return drinks_id 2 and 3. And if I gave it 5 it would return drinks_id 3.

This is what I have so far but it's currently not displaying the correct info.

```
SELECT DISTINCT drinks.id
FROM drinks
WHERE drinks.id NOT IN
(
    SELECT drinks.id
    FROM ingredients 
        JOIN drinks ON ingredients.drinks_id = drinks.id 
    WHERE ingredients.ingredients_master_id NOT IN
    (
        2,3,4,5,6
    )
);
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What about my questions doesn't follow that? I gave my table and the code I currently have and stated what result I'm trying to get.

Comment: My sense of it is that explaining the link defeats the point of providing the link

Answer (score 0):

> And I'm looking for a query where I can give it a list of ingredients_master_id such as 2,4 and it returns all of the drinks_id's that have exactly 2,4.

You can use `group by` and having:

```
select drinks_id
from t
group by drinks_id
having sum( ingredients_master_id in (2, 4) ) = 2;
```

The "= 2" is the size of the list, so you need to adjust that for different lists.

Comment: does that account for the single case as well? If you give it 2,4,5 I need it to return rows that only have 2 in the drinks_id column as well as rows that have 2,4 and 5 in the drinks_id column

Comment: @user2570937 . . . No.  That is not what this question is asking for, based on what I interpret as the question (which I have not referenced in the answer).

Answer (score 0):

You probably achieve the desired result using `not exists` as follows:

```
Select t.* 
  From your_table t
 Where t.ingredients_master_id in (2,4,5)
   And not exists
       (Select 1 from your_table tt
         Where tt.drinks_id = t.drinks_id
           And tt.ingredients_master_id not in (2,4,5))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use as below:

```
select drink_id
from (
select drink_id,listagg(ingredients_master_id,',')  within group( order by ingredients_master_id) val from <Table> group by drink_id)
where case
when instr('**2,4,5**',val)> 0
Then 'Y'
else 'N'
end = 'Y';
```